# what's main use of yield method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, block

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does it mean to yield within a block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419780/what-does-it-mean-to-yield-within-a-block)

i have to use yield method with ruby Blocks, Proc and lambda but any other make its clear answer anybody can explain. thanks in advance

Comment: See: [What does it mean to yield within a block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419780/what-does-it-mean-to-yield-within-a-block)

Comment: Show example of what you mean.

Comment: do you wanna examples of advantages of using yield method in real life examples?

Comment: The linked duplicate is about the `yield` *keyword*. The OP is asking about the `yield` *method*. Those two are completely different.

Comment: Note: I *do* support closing the question because it is, well, a bad question (no research effort, unclear, badly formatted etc.) but I'm not sure it is a duplicate of the linked question.